# git commit --amend сбросил статусы modified

Tags: git, git-commit

После выполнения commit выяснилось, что не был добавлен один файл. Файл добавил и выполнил git commit --amend. В проекте были и другие файлы со статусом modified, но после выполнения последней команды файлов со статусом modified не стало (изменения в файлах остались).
Как можно вернуться к состоянию до выполнения команды git commit --amend?

Comment: а может была выполнена команда `git commint -a --amend` или `git commit -amend` ?

Comment: Да, скорее всего был указан параметр -а. Вернулся к предыдущему состоянию через команду git reset --soft HEAD@{1}. Все модифицированные файлы оказались проиндексированы.

Comment: теперь просто поубирайте ненужные файлы через git reset HEAD файл

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git не сбросил статусы modified, а закоммитил эти файлы. Ваш вопрос сводится к тому, как через amend "раскоммитить" их обратно